# WebAPI .NET Core Some of my Requests are working properly, some of are Not Founded (404). I couldn't understand why

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

When I publish at my own server, I am not getting an error. However, when I hosting the project, sometimes ı am geting the error, I believe it could be IIS configuration mistakes.According to my observations:
1.URl is correct
2.My server is working properly.
3.Some Hosting requests sometimes working, sometimes not found (404).
Hosting IIS version 10.0.14
.NET Core 3.1

Comment: Share your relevant resources with us where you are getting this 404 error so that we can have a look on this.

Comment: Because of the privacy policy of my company; I cant give that much detail. But In my opinion, the project which is published on IIS .NET Core project, has some problems with  some requests. It gives me an error (404 not found). Thats why, I think IIS broadcast break could be the problem. The same request is not the problem; but the time of the requests cause it. I mean, the same request may not get the error but sometimes the request get an error but sometimes not. Is it more clearied now?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.